# iOS 8 doesn't detect touch on SKSpriteNodes

Tags: xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I'm testing my app on iOS 8.1 simulator and it doesn't recognize touches on `SKSpriteNodes`. If I run the same app on iOS 9.3, everything works fine. How can I avoid this problem? I've tried resettig the simulator, but that didn't do any good either. Also, I don't get any errors upon touching the `nodes`, so I'm confused how to fix this issue.

Edit:

I just tried it on an actual iPhone running on iOS 8.2, and it does the same thing.

This is what my `touches` code is

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches
    let location = touch.first!.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if (node.name == "playbutton") {

        self.runAction(buttonClick)
        let menuScene = ModesScene(size: self.size)
        menuScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
        let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
        self.view?.presentScene(menuScene, transition: reveal)
    }
```

}